# Can not reach Guests over VPN tunnel

Tags: vmware-esxi, cisco

I have a simple lab setup here. ESXi host running three 2008 server guests. The ESXi management NIC is on 172.28.23.x/24 network and the guest servers are on the same subnet as well.From subnet 172.28.23.x, I can reach my guests fine ... guests are pointing to the right gateway and can reach the internet,

I setup a Remote VPN tunnel on a Cisco ASA: 172.28.25.X/24. Over the VPN tunnel, I can use vSphere Client to connect to the ESXi host:172.28.23.3. I cannot hit any of the guests on subnet 172.28.23.X over the same VPN tunnel.

Is there anything I need to do from ESXi to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues with our ESX 3.x servers when using multiple NICs as part of a vSwitch.  Are you using trunking between your ESXi server and your switch?  If so, what method are you using on ESXi for Failover and Load Balancing?  On our switches, which are Enterasys, you have to use IP Hash for the Load Balancing, or you will find that it filters out ranges of IP addresses from talking to other hosts on the network.  You will also find that this changes every 20 minutes or so (whatever the switch's MAC cache is set to), which might explain why it worked from the local subnet but by the time you try it over the VPN, it has changed again...
Not positive this is your issue, but thought it might help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If network adapter on ESX Virtual machine is type E1000 (1 Gbit) cisco VPN tunel is OK and connection over IPSEC tunel IS OK, too (for example RDP connection). 
If you use network adapter type vmxnet3 (10 Gbit), cisco client connect to VPN site, but other services over tunel don't function.